# How to ignore a method call inside a method that is being tested?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, apache-kafka, mockmvc

I am trying to make a test pass with mockmvc and it is failing with the following error message:

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException

We have Kafka in our service layer as a dependency, and it is being called inside the method we are testing.
Is there a way to ignore that specific call during tests?
In the example below, we want to ignore the `notifyHrcOfInfectedUser()` during testing.

```
public UserDto changeInfectionStatus(String deviceId) {
    User user = this.userRepository.findById(deviceId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Could not find user with id " + deviceId));

    if (!hasPassedTwoWeeksMinimumRecoveryTime(user))
        throw new InfectionStatusException("Unable to change infection status since it has not been at least" +
                " two weeks since the last change.");

    UserDto updatedUser = updateStatus(user).convertToDto();
    notifyHrcOfInfectedUser(updatedUser.isInfected(), deviceId); // <-- Ignore this call during tests
    return updatedUser;
}

private void notifyHrcOfInfectedUser(boolean isInfected, String deviceId) {
    if (isInfected)
        kafkaSender.publish("infection-contact", deviceId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to mock the kafkaSender object? Then we can do something like...

```
final KafkaSender mockKafkaSender = Mockito.mock(KafkaSender.class);
Mockito.doNothing().when(mockKafkaSender).publish(any(),any());
```

Update...

Or to be more accurate

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(mockKafkaSender).publish(eq("infection-contact"),eq(expectedDeviceId));
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it!